# Rest Service URI mapping to Java Inner Classes

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have to model the rest service operations where I am trying to create a URI to hit Java Inner classes. Let me know if this can be achieved using Rest Web Service? I am using rest easy for my services.

**Edit:** (using code provided by answer from peeskillet)

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
at  org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407)

Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8081 refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is a bit unclear. Please post some code that demonstrates the problem, and what expected output you want

Comment: If say /rest/message/123 is my rest URI for getting data for 123 ID. Now I want to create a URI such that I will have inner class called Comment inside Message. So I want to know If I can create a service like /rest/message/comment/12. Let me know if I am sounding clear.

Comment: So the Comment is just a model class right (to model the incoming JSON)? Not a resource class?

Comment: Comments should be a resource class

Comment: Please advise if a resource class can be made as Inner class to other class

Comment: I have to consume services for two events A and B. Now B is more like enrich data of A, meaning B has additional data with union of A. So my producer is giving me one URI and thought is while consuming I can create class A with inner class B for consuming.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please advise if a resource class can be made as Inner class to other class

Yes it is possible, but we **cannot** simply annotate the inner class path `@Path` and expect the call to get there. We need to use "Sub-Resource Locators". Basically, it can be a method only annotated with `@Path`, that will return an instance of the inner resource class. SOmething like

```
@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response getMessage(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        return Response.ok("messages, id: " + id).build();
    }

    @Path("/{id}/comments")
    public CommentsResource getComments() {
        return new CommentsResource();
    }

    public class CommentsResource {

        @GET
        @Path("/{id}")
        public Response getComment(@PathParam("id") int id) {
            return Response.ok("Hello Sub-Resource Locators").build();
        }
    }
}
```

We can test it

```
@Test
public void testResteasy() {
    WebTarget target = client.target(TestPortProvider.generateURL(BASE_URI))
            .path("messages").path("1234").path("comments").path("5678");
    Response response = target.request().get();
    System.out.println("Status:" + response.getStatus());
    System.out.println("Response: " + response.readEntity(String.class));
    response.close();
}
```

And we'll get the response `Hello Sub-Resource Locators`

---

**Further Reading**

- See [JAX-RS Resource Locators and Sub Resources](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/JAX-RS_Resource_Locators_and_Sub_Resources.html)

---

**EDIT:**

Base on the error you've provided, the `TestPortProvider` will use port 8081, and start off your URI with `http://localhost:8081`. What you pass to `gererateURL` will be appended. Normally I use this with embedded server tests. But if you are running the actual server, it will most likely be on port 8080. I would suggest just passing the String base URL instead, something like:

```
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/MyApp/rest")
        .path("messages").path("1234").path("comments").path("5678");
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was looking but when compiling the test code i am getting error as posted. Please advise.

Comment: Sorry, the test code `TestPortProvider` is part of a test framework I like to use. You can replace `TestPortProvider.generateURL(BASE_URI)` with the complete base URI, like `http://localhost:8080/api`. The rest of the URI is set programmatically through `path` method chaining. So the final URI will be something like `http://localhost:8080/api/messages/1234/comments/5678`. You need to determine for yourself what the base is

Comment: You could alternatively try and type the url in the browser to see it work.

Comment: Yeah I did the same. But I am getting error while receiving the response on line Response response = target.request().get(); Any thoughts on these. Please advise

Comment: Working on browser or any restclients its working perfectly fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66091/discussion-between-skanda-and-peeskillet).